# How to use font-face to read font files in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I had my templates in simple HTML but when I put my templates, scripts and css in the Umbraco site. The fonts stopped being picked up.

At first I thought it was a path thing, but it wasn't. Whenever I try to type the URL of the referenced font I get an error.

> Page not found No umbraco document matches the url
>   'localhost/.../bliss-heavy.otf'
>
> umbraco tried this to match it using this xpath query'/root/*
>   [@urlName = "login"] | /root/*/* [@urlName = "login"]')

I know my path is correct because when I try a slightly different path I get the obvious error:

> Server Error in Application "LOCAL.DOTAGENCYLONDON.CO.UK"
>
> Internet Information Services 7.5 Error Summary HTTP Error 404.0 - Not
>   Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

In my web.config file I have:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".air" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

What should I look for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@amelvin, thanks for your answer. That happens because I have no template or even node for the the /login.aspx URL.

But why was site being redirect to /login.aspx? It turned out that the app pool user didn't have permission to read the font files.

Once I overwrote the app pool credentials with mine in the IIS website, it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You first error looks like when you try to preview or browse to an umbraco page that has no template selected - go to the properties tab of the page and see if there is a template chosen:

[image]